# How to replace a lowercase character to uppercase in a text file

Tags: c

I'm converting each lowercase character into uppercase, but it's not replacing in the file. What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    FILE *file;
    char ch;
    file = fopen("file.txt", "r+");
    if (file == NULL) {
        printf("Error");
        exit(1);
    } else {
        while ((ch = fgetc(file)) != EOF) {
            if (ch >= 96 && ch <= 123) {
                ch = ch - 32;
                putc(ch, file);
            }
        }
        fclose(file);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Look up `isalpha()`, `islower()`, `isupper()`, `tolower()`, `toupper()` from `<ctype.h>`.  Don't use `96` to mean back-quote (97 is `'a'`) or `123` to mean `{` (`'z'` is 122); use the literals because you won't get the numbers wrong.

Comment: What are you doing wrong? [`fgetc` returns an int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35356322/difference-between-int-and-char-in-getchar-fgetc-and-putchar-fputc). Hardcoding `a` and `z` (and with invalid values. Reading and writing to the same text file with interleaved operations, not using `perror` to write the error message, not using the `islower` function, not actually using the `tolower` function...

Comment: And forgetting to use `flush` after each write, thus causing undefined behaviour.

Comment: Note that the `else` clause could be made 'unconditional', avoiding a level of indentation, because the body of the `if` ends with `exit()` so the code will never get beyond that.  If there was a `return` there, you could also drop the `else`. Nevertheless, what you've got is OK.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: a positioning operation (e.g. `fseek()`) is sufficient; `fflush()` is over-heavy.

Comment: Yeah `fseek` is sufficient, but using `fseek` without `ftell` will result in undefined behaviour on text files.

Comment: (and yeah toupper)

Comment: that is why you should almost every time check for errors (here the return value of `putc()`)

Comment: A couple things you have to know before you start: 1) Which character encoding is the file using? 2) For which culture/locale's rules do you want to use for the case conversion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that with [`fopen/'+'`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.5.3p7), switching from reading to writing requires an intermediate call to a file positioning function, e.g. `fseek`:

> **7.21.5.3 The fopen function**
>
> (7) When a file is opened with update mode ('+' as the second or third
>   character in the above list of mode argument values), both input and
>   output may be performed on the associated stream. However, **output
>   shall not be directly followed by input without an intervening call to
>   the fflush function or to a file positioning function (fseek, fsetpos,
>   or rewind)**, and input shall not be directly followed by output without
>   an intervening call to a file positioning function, unless the input
>   operation encounters end- of-file. Opening (or creating) a text file
>   with update mode may instead open (or create) a binary stream in some
>   implementations.

So you probably have to write something like

```
fseek (fp , -1, SEEK_CUR);
putc(ch,file);
fseek (fp , 0, SEEK_CUR);
```

Note, however, that replacing characters one by one in a (possibly) large file is rather inefficient. The preferred way would be to read in one file, do the conversions and write to another file, and - in the end - replace the one file with the other one. If that cannot be achieved, try at least to read in / convert / write back larger chunks (not byte by byte).

Just to check whether converting byte by byte is really inefficient, I compared it to a chunk-by-chunk - approach. It turns out - at least at my machine - that chunk-by-chunk in this test is 500 times faster than byte-by-byte. The file size is about 100k:

```
int main(void) {
    FILE *file;
    int ch;
    file = fopen("/Users/stephanl/Desktop/ImplantmedPic_Storeblok.jpg", "rb+");
    if (file == NULL) {
        printf("Error: cannot open file.txt\n");
        return 1;
    } else {
        clock_t t1 = clock();

        // The following variant takes about 900 ticks:
        unsigned char buffer[1000];
        unsigned long l;
        while (1) {
            unsigned long fpi = ftell(file);
            l=fread(buffer, 1, 1000, file);
            if (l==0)
                break;

            for (int i=0;i<l;i++) {
                buffer[i]=~buffer[i];
            }

            fseek(file, fpi, SEEK_SET);
            fwrite(buffer,1,l, file);
            fseek(file, 0L, SEEK_CUR);
        }


        // this variant takes about 500.000 ticks
        while ((ch = fgetc(file)) != EOF) {
                fseek(file, -1L, SEEK_CUR);
                putc(~ch, file);
                fseek(file, 0L, SEEK_CUR);
        }

        fclose(file);
        clock_t t2 = clock();
        printf ("difference: %ld \n", t2-t1);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: At least it is standard I/O using buffering, so the `putc()` calls are not doing a physical `write()` system call.  But you're diagnosis is spot on.  I'm moderately sure this is a duplicate, but I'm not sure I can be bothered to find the duplicate.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: I think - though not having tested it - that switching from input to output and back introduces a lot of overhead (probably flushing the buffers). And there is a similar answer (here)[https://stackoverflow.com/a/46152654/2630032], but the char-by-char - issue made me not marking the question as duplicate.

Comment: In a single-threaded process, there isn't (or doesn't need to be) all that much overhead.  I'm not sure how much more severe the problem is in multi-threaded processes.  And modern libraries may have to make the pessimistic assumption that they're working in a multi-threaded process.  It was a whole heap easier 30 years ago.

Comment: This is *just one thing*.

Comment: this isn't standards-compliant either. `fseek` to a position that was not returned by `ftell` will result in undefined behaviour on text files. In practice it will probably fail spectacularly on windows where `\n` results in 2 characters.

Comment: @StephanLechner: the file should be open in binary mode and `ch` should be defined with `int` type.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: Just wanted to know and tried it out: byte-by-byte is much slower than chunk-by-chunk on my machine (see edited answer).

Comment: 500 times is a big factor — bigger than I would have expected.  I don't know when that changed — or even if it changed (I no longer have access to the systems of yester-millennium that might have been relevant).  I would certainly expect byte-by-byte to be slower, but not by that margin.  Thanks for testing and reporting.  (I can't give extra up-votes, I'm afraid.)

Answer (score 3):

You have to open another file to write.

```
fileOut = fopen("fileOut.txt", "w");
```

`ch` must be integer.

```
int ch;
```

Check men page like this.

```
#man fgetc
```

And:

```
putc(ch,fileOut);
```

should be out of `if` block.

Comment: This is another way to do it, but it isn't 100% mandatory.  Variations on what the question proposes can work fine.

Comment: this is the 100 % *sane* way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- opening the file in read+update mode (`"r+"`) is tricky: you must call `fseek()` between read and write operations, otherwise the behavior is undefined. Furthermore, you must open the file in binary mode for `fseek()` to operate correctly and portably on byte offsets.
- `ch` must be defined as `int` for `EOF` to be properly detected.
- hardcoding the values of `'a'` and `'z'` as `96` and `123` is non portable and error prone, in fact `'a'` is `97` in ASCII, not `96` and `'z'` is `122`, not `123`.  Use the functions from `<ctype.h>` for best portability and readability.
- shifting by `32` only works for ASCII, use `toupper()` instead.
- you forgot to include `<stdlib.h>` that declares the `exit()` function.

Here is a corrected (simplistic and inefficient) version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    FILE *file;
    int ch;
    file = fopen("file.txt", "rb+");
    if (file == NULL) {
        printf("Error: cannot open file.txt\n");
        return 1;
    } else {
        while ((ch = fgetc(file)) != EOF) {
            if (islower(ch)) {
                fseek(file, -1L, SEEK_CUR);
                putc(toupper(ch), file);
                fseek(file, 0L, SEEK_CUR);
            }
        }
        fclose(file);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `toupper(3)` function (or macro call) from `#include <ctype.h>`, so you don't have to know which character set is available at your installation.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    FILE *file;
    int ch;
    file = fopen("file.txt", "r+");
    if (file == NULL) {
        printf("Error");
        exit(1);
    } else {
        while ((ch = fgetc(file)) != EOF) {
            putc(toupper(ch), file);
        }
        fclose(file);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

## NOTE

There's a flaw in your original code... you check `ch` to be lowercase and only output it if it happens to be.  You have to output all uppercase and no-case characters also.... so don't put the `putc(3)` call in the `if` block.  My code just output all the characters converted to uppercase with the function.  Also, you have to define `ch` as `int`, as required by `fgetc(3)`, `toupper(3)` and `putc(3)`.