# What does the g stand for in gcount, tellg and seekg?

Tags: c++, iostream

What does the *g* stand for in `std::iostream`'s `gcount`, `tellg` and `seekg` members? And the *p* in `pcount`, `tellp` and `seekp`?

Why aren't they called just `count`, `tell` and `seek`?

Comment: It it was called only plain `seek` (for example), then you can't have separate pointers for the input and output parts of a combined input-*and*-output stream.

Comment: By the way: The answers explain the p too. It may be more useful to edit the question for the p.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

In streams supporting both read and write, you actually have two positions, one for read (i.e. "get" denoted by "g") and one for write (i.e. "put" denoted by a "p").

And that's why you have a `seekp` (inherited from `basic_ostream`), and a `seekg` (inherited from `basic_istream`).

Side note: The language C has - in contrast to C++ - only one such function `fseek` for both pointers; There it is necessary to re-position the pointer when switching from read to write and vice versa (cf., for example, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46152654/2630032) answer). To avoid this, C++ offers separate functions for read and write, respectively.

Answer (score 56):

C++ offers two pointers while navigating the file: the *get* pointer and the *put* pointer. The first one is used for read operations, the second one for write operations.

> - `seekg()` is used to move the **g**et pointer to a desired location with respect to a reference point.
> - `tellg()` is used to know where the **g**et pointer is in a file.
> - `seekp()` is used to move the **p**ut pointer to a desired location with respect to a reference point.
> - `tellp()` is used to know where the **p**ut pointer is in a file.

<sup>Main source: [Quora](https://www.quora.com/What-are-seekg-seekp-tellg-and-tellp-functions), answer by *Gunjan B. Yadav* on Dec 1, 2017.</sup>

Comment: Why do C++ standards people name APIs as if keyboards have per-keystroke costs. 

Comment: @Alexander : to avoid people getting paid by keystroke, obviously. Clever and business-oriented programmers naturally overcome this problem by inventing their own types and wrappers for the standard library, which of course always works out perfectly and has no disadvantages whatsoever.

Comment: @Alexander https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/high_resolution_clock

Comment: @Ajay I like it!