# Replacing the vowels of a file's content using fopen with "+r" mode

Tags: c, file, replace, fopen

In the below code I am:

- Creating a file with the name the user inputs.
- Writing in that file a predefined sentence: `Hello, how are you? Hope you are having a great day.`
- Asking the user what vowel they want to replace with '_'

This means that if the user entered the vowel `a`, I would want the contents of the file to end up looking like this: `Hello, how _re you? Hope you _re h_ving _ gre_t d_y.`

I thought reopening the file in `r+` mode would do the trick, but it is not working. Could you help me figure this one out with what I already have? Thank you!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <string.h>


void identifica(void);

int main()
{

FILE *fich;
char file_name[10], vowel = 0, c = 0;

printf("Please enter the file name:\n");
gets(file_name);

fich = fopen(file_name, "w");

fputs ("Hello, how are you? Hope you are having a great day.", fich);

printf("What vowel do you want to reaplce with '_'?\n");
vowel = getchar ();

fclose(fich);
fich = NULL;

fich = fopen(file_name, "r+");

while ((c = fgetc(fich)) != EOF)
{
    if (c == vowel)
    {
        fputs ("_",fich);
    }
}

fclose(fich);
fich = NULL;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: if you want to overwrite a character that you just have read, wouldn't you have to move the write position one character backward?

Comment: you didnt say what error happens, but it's a good idea to sync the file with fflush(NULL); before you open the file a second time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C, when you open a file in update mode (e.g. with `r+`), you will have *two* positions, one for reading and one for writing. Reading per se does not (necessarily) move the write pointer, and writing does not (necessarily) move the read pointer. As defined be the standard, you have to use `fseek` or `fflush` when switching between reading and writing (cf., for example, [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46152654/2630032).

So you need to write...

```
    fseek(fich, -1, SEEK_CUR);
    fputs("_",fich);
    fseek(fich, 0, SEEK_CUR);
```

Comment: thanks for the additional information @StephanLechner! :-)

Answer (score 2):

You should put `fseek(fich, -1, SEEK_CUR);` before the statement `fputs("_",fich);`. After reading the character c, you need to step back one position to replace the right character. Once you replace the character, you can seek back to current position using `fseek(fich, 0, SEEK_CUR);`. The following code would work correctly -

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <string.h>


void identifica(void);

int main()
{

FILE *fich;
char file_name[10], vowel = 0;
int c = 0;

printf("Please enter the file name:\n");
gets(file_name);

fich = fopen(file_name, "w");

fputs ("Hello, how are you? Hope you are having a great day.", fich);

printf("What vowel do you want to reaplce with '_'?\n");
vowel = getchar ();

fclose(fich);
fich = NULL;

fich = fopen(file_name, "r+");

while ((c = fgetc(fich)) != EOF)
{
    if (c == vowel)
    {
        fseek(fich, -1, SEEK_CUR);
        fputs("_",fich);
        fseek(fich, 0, SEEK_CUR);
    }
}

fclose(fich);
fich = NULL;

return 0;
}
```

NOTE : `fgetc()` returns an `int`, not a `char`; it has to return every valid char value plus a separate value, EOF. As written, you can't reliably detect EOF. If char is an unsigned type, you'll never find EOF; So, I have replaced c with type `int`.

Comment: That was great @Abhishek! Didn't know about the `fseek()` function and will also make a note on `fgetc()` :-) Thanks very much for your quick and perfect answer! :-)

Comment: Note that the issue is not just the missing "step one back"; it is that you always have to use `fflush` or `fseek` when switching between reading and writing.